# iPhone sliding popup user interface thingy

Tags: iphone

My problem is I don't know what keywords to google for this. here is what I'm after:
I want to have a normal view with a toolbar or something like that, for example look at this screenshot:[alt text http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/4171/screenshot2009100918482.png](http://img522.imageshack.us/img522/4171/screenshot2009100918482.png)

then I want to have a "popup" sort of view activated on the view, like this:

[alt text http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/3139/screenshot2009100918484.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/3139/screenshot2009100918484.png)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a popup view on top of an existing view, all you need to do is add it as a sibling of the existing view in the view hierarchy.

```
[parentView addSubview:existingView]; // you're already adding your first view like this
[parentView addSubview:popupView];    // Subsequent addSubview calls appear on top
```

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think this kind of view is a part of the standard API, you’ll have to code it yourself. (Create a new class that inherits from `UIView`, set the desired background color, create the shadow and outline, draw the triangle at the bottom of the view etc. Maybe also make it possible to attach the view to some other control so that it would get the correct position automatically.) But let’s wait, maybe somebody knows a better solution.